# Goland doesn't see functions from another file

Tags: go, goland

I have `main.go` file

```
package main

func main() {
    func2()
}
```

`func2` is defined in `file2.go`:

```
package main

func func2(){
    ...
}
```

Everything is OK when I compile and run it from a command line:

```
go run main.go file2.go
```

But when I run it from `Goland` by pressing `RUN` it gives me an error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:95: undefined: func2
```

How should I overcome it?

Comment: Make f of  func2 in Upper case like Func2() and try..

Comment: Check Run Configuration in Goland.

Comment: It seems that Goland, when you press `RUN`, only executes `go run main.go` leaving out the `file2.go` argument. So you have to look into the settings and see if you can change it to something like `go run *.go`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `Run | Edit Configurations` and change the run configuration `Type` to point from `File` to a `Package`, then the package name must be fully qualified (for example `github.com/user/package`).

Edit:
You can also right-click on the folder and then select `Run | go test <folder name>`. This will create a run configuration of the type `Directory`.

**Note:** there are differences between the `Directory` and `Package` type configurations.